# Best way to call web service when there is internet connection

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I need some advice. I'm developing android application , The user can enter some data in the app and I need to insert it to server database when there is internet connection. If not, I store it in the local database till I detect that there's internet connection , then I'll add them to the server database.

So I have find and implement two ways to do this but I need some advice and suggestion to which one I should use and which one is better and more guaranteed than the other.

1. I'm using service that have a timer , so every minute I check if there is internet connection or not , if yes I call a web service to insert the data in the local to server database.
2. By using broadcast receiver , I registered it in the application class so whenever the device is connected I call the service that call a web service to insert the data in local to server database.

So which one you think is better and more efficient?

Comment: Sahil has given really good suggestion. You won't be able to register for internet connectivity broadcast due to background restrictions on Android Oreo+. But JobScheduler is supported only on devices starting with api 21+. So if you want to provide backwards compatibility, you should consider using WorkManger as it is latest library offered by Google for background processing. If you targeting devices with api 21+, then use JobScheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely go with second option as this is more efficient. This way you won't waste os resources on unnecessary internet connectivity check and only start service when os informs you that internet is turned on by user.

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
     * Starts job for listening to network connectivity change
     * @param context
     */
    private void startJobForListeningToNetworkConnectivityChange(@NonNull Context context) {
        JobInfo myJob = new JobInfo.Builder(mNetworkConnectivityJobId, new ComponentName(context, NetworkSchedulerService.class))
                .setRequiresCharging(false)
                .setMinimumLatency(1000)
                .setOverrideDeadline(2000)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setPersisted(false)
                .build();

        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(myJob);
    }


/**
 * This class schedules a job to listen to network connectivity change events
 */
public class NetworkSchedulerService extends JobService implements
        ConnectivityReceiver.NetworkConnectivityReceiverListener {
    private final static String CONNECTIVITY_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

    private ConnectivityReceiver mConnectivityReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mConnectivityReceiver = new ConnectivityReceiver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        registerReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver, new IntentFilter(CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        unregisterReceiver(mConnectivityReceiver);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        // Notify your app of the current network status
    }
}


/**
 * Broadcast receiver for network change
 */
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private NetworkConnectivityReceiverListener mConnectivityReceiverListener;

    /**
     *  Constructor
     * @param listener
     */
    public ConnectivityReceiver(NetworkConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
        mConnectivityReceiverListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Receiver for connectivity change event
     * @param context
     * @param intent
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mConnectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnectedToNetwork(context));
    }

    /**
     * Checks if device is connected to any network
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isConnectedToNetwork(Context context) {
        // Logic for checking internet connectivity should be written here.
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Connectivity change receiver interface
     */
    public interface NetworkConnectivityReceiverListener {
        void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
    }
}
```

Please check the above code, this is the implementation of JobScheduler.

For reference: 
https://medium.com/@iiro.krankka/its-time-to-kiss-goodbye-to-your-implicit-broadcastreceivers-eefafd9f4f8a

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own answer or delete this altogether: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a broadcast receiver is better and more efficient.

Usually, use service in android is expensive and have more trouble, a background service affected phone battery, so android OS close and prevent like this service.

For using service you must start foreground service(in android 8 and higher is coercion)

My suggestion to use a broadcast receiver for checking network is available for sending next request

Tip: if you want this check when a user inside the app, you can use an observer design pattern or use RX library

Comment: So basically what you saying is inside the broadcast receiver when the network is available I call the web service from there without even using a background service?

Comment: I say broadcast receiver when network is available to notify Webservice class to send a new request